# Vb.Net ASP.Net Shopping Cart with cookies

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, cookies, e-commerce

I am building an E-commerce website and everything went great until I started thinking about how I'm going to make my shopping cart, using cookies.

I'm using a datalist to display my products, when a user clicks on a button, I want the product ID to be stored in a cookie so when the user goes to his shopping cart, the cart checks all the ID's in the cookie and then checks in my access database which product it should add.

Does anyone know how I should make this work or have a useful tutorial? Because all the tutorials I found are in java, php, c# etc. but I need to make this in vb.net because it's a school project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it's C#.NET it would be reasonably easy to convert to VB.NET (maybe with a few discrepancies which are easily resolved). try this if you don't know _any_ C#: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Yea but it's almost impossible to find a tutorial with cookies :/ Would I be able to store an array in a cookie with the product ID's and then cycle through the array to display the products in a gridview?

Comment: Are you looking for a shopping cart tutorial with cookies or just a tutorial about cookies and ASP.Net (and not about a shopping cart?) The shopping cart aspect of this project is pretty straightforward - I would focus on how to get cookies to work using VB and ASP.Net and then build the shopping cart functionality once you're comfortable with cookies.

Comment: I know how cookies work and how to use them, you can add multiple values to a cookie but can you store multiple values with the same name? With an array for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If Request.Cookies("Winkelmand") Is Nothing Then
            Dim objCookie As New HttpCookie("Winkelmand")`

```
        objCookie.Values.Add(strProductId, strProductId)

        objCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(30)

        Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie)
    Else
        Dim objCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("Winkelmand")
        Dim strControleDubbel As String

        strControleDubbel = objCookie.Values.Item(strProductId)

        If strControleDubbel = Nothing Then
            objCookie.Values.Add(strProductId, strProductId)

            Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie)

        End If
```

This code worked!

Answer (score 0):

`Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`

```
    Dim btnShoppingCart As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)

    'get values from datalist
    Dim datalistItem As DataListItem = DirectCast(btnShoppingCart.NamingContainer, DataListItem)
    'productId
    Dim lblProductId As Label = DirectCast(datalistItem.FindControl("lblProductId"), Label)
    Dim strProductId As String = lblProductId.Text

    Dim objCookie As New HttpCookie("ShoppingCart")

    objCookie.Value = strProductId

    objCookie.Expires = Now.AddDays(30)

    Response.Cookies.Add(objCookie)
End Sub
```

End Class    
If I do it like this, I just get one value saved in the cookie, any way to get multiple values?

If I would use objCookie.Values.add("ID", strProductId) I can only save 1 ID to it, right?